# ASP.Net MVC: When form post then one view model property getting null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have simple form where one dropdown and one submit button. i have two index function one for get and one for form post. when i select a product from dropdown and click on submit button then my index action getting invoke but there i notice my products property getting null. see my code please and tell me where i made the mistake.

### view code

```
@model  AuthTest.Models.SampleViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DateValTest</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Products, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", style = "padding-top:0px;" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProductId, new SelectList(Model.Products, "ID", "Name"), "-- Select Product--")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedProductId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

}
```

### model code

```
  public class Product
    {
        public int ID { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
    }

    public class SampleViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Products")]
        public List<Product> Products { set; get; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select any one")]
        public int SelectedProductId { set; get; }    
    }
```

### controller code

```
public class TestValController : Controller
{
    // GET: TestVal
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var SampleVM = new SampleViewModel();
        SampleVM.Products = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product{ ID=1, Name="IPhone" },
            new Product{ ID=2, Name="MacBook Pro" },
            new Product{ ID=3, Name="iPod" }           
        };
        return View(SampleVM);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SampleViewModel vm)
    {

        var SampleVM = new SampleViewModel();
        SampleVM.Products = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product{ ID=1, Name="IPhone" },
            new Product{ ID=2, Name="MacBook Pro" },
            new Product{ ID=3, Name="iPod" }           
        };

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(vm);
        else
            return View(SampleVM);
    }
}
```

when i debug second action then i saw `vm products property getting null`
please tell me where i made the mistake?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not making any mistake, You are not getting the list of products back because you are not including them in the HTML input form.

If you want to include the list of products you can add the following inside the input form

```
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Products[i].Name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Products[i].ID)
            </div>
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mou,

Please modify your razor view and try this.
In Razor View nowhere you have specified the Http verb(Get,Post).

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "TestVal", FormMethod.Post)
```

Comment: still the vm products property is null.